# Are zombie chases suppose to be this rare?

Tags: zombies-run

I downloaded the Zombies, Run! game on my iPod.

I enjoy the storyline and stuff, but there are very few zombie chases, even if I set it to 6 chases an hour and I need to increase my speed +30% to outrun.

I jog a steady pace for a while, but I still don't get any chases.

When I do get chases, though, 1 of 2 things will happen:

- it will beep 3 times, and the zombies will magically disappear. (Happens in supply runs most of the time)
- very rarely, it will start a normal zombie chase in a mission. (This appears to be random, as I have had 4 missions without a chase, today.)

My guess is that it would have to do with the tracking. Are the chases suppose to be this rare?

Even at a setting of 6 per hour, I still go several hours without a chase.

Comment: The new release is still very buggy. I suggest you go to the [help center](https://sixtostart.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/categories/200201673-Zombies-Run-) and write a [bug report](https://sixtostart.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).

Answer (score 1):

Zombie chases in story missions are tied to specific moments after the story clip has played, so the fact you're getting only one after four missions is a bug (most missions have two or three triggers). I'd contact Six to Start.